# Why am I unable to access my server from outside the local network?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I wanted to setup and understand basic networking / port forwarding for a number of purposes. I only have a windows 7 machine so I setup a static local ip address from the network adapter settings using the same subnet, default gateway and dns addresses and a local ip with the last set of numbers altered. From the router page I made sure upnp and port forwarding are on and forwarded a number of ports to the aformentioned static ip. I also switched off the router's and OS's firewalls just in case.

From here I could easily access the servers from any device connected directly through my router and successfully visited a mock website using http://123.456.1.78:80/site and viewed a video stream with the rtmp protocol through VLC using rtmp://123.456.1.78:1935 on my phone or laptop but when I tried to do the same from an outside network (using the public ip this time) it always fails to connect.

Is there something I am missing or is this the fault or my ISP?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a regular internet connection it is very likely you are behind a CG-NAT and your public IP address is non routable. There isn't much you can do aside from talking to your ISP (not happening)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with a lot of this networking stuff and only had the time to skim over the description of CG-NAT and it sounds like taking control away from the user to me. If that's the case i'll have a talk with them. thanks

Comment: If you didn't get why it works when connected on local network, then remember that IP packets will be sent to your router which will realize that it has the address you assigned, and proceed with port forwarding the way you set it up. In such case even if you used the public IP there will only be local traffic, hence it works.